# Converting Jenkins Project to Pipeline and unable to run ant build get 'cmd' is not recognized

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline

Project builds just fine trying to convert this to run as pipeline.  Get error -  Running batch script
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Used Convert This Job to Pipeline which didn't quite succeed and had other issues (separate issue).  Created Jenkins File and copied in and modified the Pipeline script.
I have tried both WithEnv and WithAnt and same results.  Additionally found a note out there and put C:\Windows\System32 in the PATH on the Agent and still get the error.  So I'm not sure what I'm missing since I have no issues with my original project and should be calling the same tools I set in Global Tools Config

```
stage ('PowerSuite - Build') {
 agent {
        node {
          label 'jenkinsclient2'
        }

      } 
    steps {
        withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool 'JDK_1.7.0_09'}", "PATH=${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin"]){
        withAnt(installation: 'Ant 1.7.0') {
        echo 'Jenkins client 2 running PowerSuite Build'

        bat "ant -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -buildfile C:\\Builds\\Dev\\Powersuite\\build\\project.xml -Dbuild_type=DEV -DdeployDir=\\\\cifs\\Builds\\PowerSuite\\DEVTest -lib .\buildtoolkit clean ear"  
        } 
    }
    }
    }
```

Have Ant run the build same as the Jenkins Project

Comment: Well - simple fix by adding in PATH=${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin;C:\\Windows\\System32"])  but now doesn't like me specifying -Xms1024m   - get Unknown argument: -Xmx1024m

Comment: Regarding the problem you just mentioned, try adding an environment variable named `ANT_OPTS` in your `withEnv` block and specify your memory settings there.